# google signIn not working in release apk android

Tags: android, google-signin

In release apk, google sign is not working but in debug apk it is working. I have updated sha1 also. In release sha1, debug sha1 both are same. i checked in gradle console. I referred more tutorials, stack overflow solutions. i can't find the solution. is there any better solution?

Comment: No way, debug and release should not be same. Double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to find release sha1 :

Type below command in your cmd or terminal:

`keytool -list -v -keystore D:\filepath\YourAPP.jks -alias XYZ`

and debug sha1 :

[image: ![Go to far left[![][1][1]]

Please refer to the following images and get the SHA-1 key
[image: Refresh]

[image: View in console panel at bottom]

Comment: yes, i used this one. but not working in release apk

Comment: `keytool -list -v -keystore D:\filepath\YourAPP.jks -alias XYZ` is this you used.

Comment: Make sure make same system release apk where you created release sha1.

Comment: I have a doubt, in android studio Sha1 is different and i generated in mac using terminal sha1 is different. which sha1 is update in google console.

Comment: One is for debug and other is for release.

Comment: But if you want it to work with live only then you should add **terminal** one sha1

Comment: ok, i add two sha1s in OAuth 2.0 client IDs. then is there any further steps?

Comment: Great if you seems it useful please accept the answer.

Comment: google sign is not working in production. i tested both debug and release apk both are working. I have updated sha1 for both debug and release, i generated signed in release apk it is working but in production not working google signin. is there any solution?

Comment: We can find release sha1 from publish console also, but release sha1 is always same. Put only release sha1 in google console then check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your release sha1 key into the google console
To get release sha1 key you can try
For Windows

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {path to keystore(jks file)} -alias {alias_name}
```

For Linux/Max

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v  -keystore ~/path_to_your_keystore
```

add that sha1 key to google console

Comment: I have a doubt, in android studio Sha1 is different and i generated in mac using terminal sha1 is different. which sha1 is update in google console.

Comment: Use the sha1 you get from terminal and add that in google play console.